# LittleProxy to handle both HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: java, http-proxy, little-proxy

I am currently using LittleProxy to add some headers to a request and forward it to a server using HTTP.

I have been trying to do the same for HTTPS calls but failing.

How can I achieve the same for both HTTP and HTTPS?

Comment: What is your exact problem? Is MITM enabled in your proxy config?

Comment: @Ben how to enable MITM ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://github.com/ganskef/LittleProxy-mitm
You can then intercept https requests and add headers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your LittleProxy as the endpoint of the TLS connection. So you then you can add your headers and then you can forward th connection to your web server.